# XgBoost validate_features argument in predict method. What does validate_features do?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

Can anyone please help me to understand the significance of

```
validate_features
```

argument of predict method and how does it affect the predication from the tree.

I am using python API for the Xgboost.

Answer (score 0):

> When this is **True**, validate that the Booster’s and data’s **feature_names** are **identical**. Otherwise, it is assumed that the **feature_names** are the **same**.